# Unexpected token for private variables in TypeScript 2.9.1

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-cli

I am currently working with VueJS and TypeScript 2.9.1. I am creating a library and converted it to typescript later on.

When building the lib with vue-cli the typescript linter says the following error message:

```js
WARNING  Compiled with 1 warnings                                                                                                                                                                            5:57:15 PM
error: Parsing error: Unexpected token

  36 |
  37 | export default class Graph {
> 38 |   private _nodes: GraphNodeList = {}
     |           ^
  39 |   private _edges: EdgeList = {}
  40 |
  41 |   layout: Layout | undefined at src/Graph.ts:38:11:
```

If I delete the 'private' keyword the errors are gone. But I know that the private keyword is allowed in typescript. They also write it like this in the documentation.

Does anyone know why this happens? Would be cool to use private variables in the future.

tslint.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "es2015",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Package.json (reduced)

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib src/main.ts",
    "dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development --name vue-flowy --watch --target lib src/main.ts",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^5.4.0",
    "dagre-d3-renderer": "^0.5.8",
    "graphlibrary": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-class-component": "^6.0.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/debug": "^0.0.30",
    "@types/jest": "^22.0.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "^3.0.0-beta.11",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.0-beta.11",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.0.0-beta.11",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-beta.11",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^3.0.0-beta.11",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^3.0.0-beta.11",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "jest": "^22.4.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "^4.7.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "ts-jest": "^22.4.6",
    "typescript": "^2.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-eslint-parser": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "module": "dist/vue-flowy.es.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Patcher56/vue-flowy.git"
  },
  "types": "types/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
  "main": "dist/vue-flowy.umd.js",
  ...
  "peerDependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.16"
  },
  ...
}
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    extract: false
  }
}
```

build/index.ts

```
'use strict'
// Template version: 1.2.7
// see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack for documentation.
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  dev: {
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {},
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    autoOpenBrowser: true,
    errorOverlay: true,
    notifyOnErrors: true,
    poll: false,
    useEslint: true,
    showEslintErrorsInOverlay: true,
    devtool: '#source-map',
    cacheBusting: true,
    cssSourceMap: false
  },

  bundle: {
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    productionSourceMap: false,
    devtool: '#source-map',
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  },

  docs: {
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../docs/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../docs'),
    assetsPublicPath: '',
    devtool: '#source-map',
    productionSourceMap: false
  }
}
```

Link to whole Repository:
https://github.com/Patcher56/vue-flowy/tree/02c6861e58ffe9ed2f38282e457e7524b8f4cbe8

Comment: Out of curiousity, what happens if you remove the `_`?

Comment: seems like a tslint thing, not a compiler issue

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Yeah I thought that too but that does not fix the problem unfortunately

Comment: Please update the question with a [mcve] and the config of the tool you're getting this error from (along with the tool's name -- e.g., you've said "the typescript linter" -- do you mean `tslint`? or built-in linting done by `tsc`? or ...?).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added a reproduction link to github. It shows the actual state of the project. Yes, I am using tslint which was automatically condigured by vue-cli (@vue/typescript)

Comment: @Patcher56 *"I added a reproduction link to github"* The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh god - will add some code snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up my code a lot and removed some unused dependencies.
I also cleaned up my tslint.json. The problem is gone now.

I think the problem was that there were too many dependencies blocking each other.
Sorry for the time invested by everyone answered this question.

Answer (score 4):

You can either stick to conventions that says that private variables shouldn't have a leading underscore, or, if you insist on using it, put this in your tslint.json

```
"variable-name": [true, "allow-leading-underscore"]
```

---

Sidenote:

I don't find a explicit vue styleguide for typescript, but the angular equivalent is found here: [Angular styleguide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#properties-and-methods)

Comment: The underscore is not the problem. The message still appears if I change _nodes to graphNodes.